# iOS: UIImagePickerController Overlay property Detects CameraSource Change

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

**Background:** I am implementing a face mask to help people focus their camera and to produce a uniform result across every picture. Sadly, the face mask needs to adjust its size while switching between front and back facing camera to provide a great guideline for people.

**Problem:** I have been trying to detect this switch between camera to adjust my face mask accordingly. I have not yet found how to detect it.

**Additional Info:** I have tried looking into delegate and/or subclassing the pickerController. There are no methods visible for this detection. My last resort would be having a thread keep on checking camera source and adjust if needed. I welcome anything better :)

Answer (score -1):

I would take a look at the UIImagePickerController documentation around cameraDevice property.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController_Class.pdf

You can create an observer to run a selector when it changes:

http://farwestab.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/using-observers-on-ios/

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Pardon me for not being to find this notification in the pdf. Please be very specific for me. I am a bit slow.